# Etiquetas en gráficos con matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster

necesito ayuda con la librería matplotlib.
Mi profesor me facilito un código para hacer cluster sobre unos datos en un csv para un trabajo y me sería de mucha ayuda que al momento de plotear los datos el gráfico añadiera una etiqueta con el id de cada dato o algo similar en vez de mostrar solo agrupaciones de puntos coloreados. Adjunto el código a continuación e imagen del primer gráfico:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

random_state = 170


ar = pd.read_csv("Tiempo etapa - pre.csv", encoding="LATIN-1",
             usecols=["A","B","C","D","E","F"])

print(ar.head())


y_pred = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=random_state).fit_predict(ar)

print(y_pred)


plt.subplot(221)
plt.scatter(ar["E"], ar["F"], c=y_pred)
plt.title("E y F")
plt.show()


n_digits = 2
reduced_ar = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(ar)


plt.scatter(reduced_ar[:, 0], reduced_ar[:, 1], c=y_pred)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me gustaría que al lado de cada punto apareciera una etiqueta con el id correspondiente

De momento solo uso las columnas con los datos necesarios para el cluster, sin embargo, el csv posee una columna previa a la columna "A" con los id de cada caso.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma más simple de incorporar etiquetas a cada punto es usar la función [`annotate()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) de la siguiente forma:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Seteo Semilla para hacer el ejemplo reproducible
np.random.seed(1)

# Genero 20 valores x, y
x = np.random.random(20)
y = np.random.random(20)

# Genero 20 ids para los puntos
ids = np.random.randint(100, size=20).astype('str')

plt.scatter(x, y)

# Etiquetar los puntos
for i, txt in enumerate(ids):
    plt.annotate(str(txt), (x[i],y[i]))

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De verdad agradezco tus indicaciones, me sirvio bastante para un informe que estoy realizando. Mil gracias!!!!!